# Python 3 вывод результата цикла for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть цикл

```
for slug in urls:
newUrl = url.replace('?page=1', slug)
response = requests.get(newUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
for n, i in enumerate(items, start=n):
    itemName = i.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()
    itemPrice = i.find('h5').text
    res = print(f'{n}:  {itemPrice} за {itemName}')
```

В последней строке объявил переменную **res**
Все отрабатывает хорошо, но потом хочу еще раз ее вывести путем простого

```
print(res)
```

Выдает None, объясните как такое реализуется на питоне, хочу эту переменную использовать например для такой конструкции

```
with open("items.html", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file: 
        with redirect_stdout(file):
             print(f'{n}:  {itemPrice} за {itemName}')
```

При таком раскладе выдает последнее значение - например 6:  $49.99 за Short Chiffon Dress
А должно быть соответственно списком

```
1:  $24.99 за Short Dress
2:  $29.99 за Patterned Slacks
3:  $49.99 за Short Chiffon Dress
4:  $59.99 за Off-the-shoulder Dress
5:  $24.99 за V-neck Top
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = print(f'{n}:  {itemPrice} за {itemName}')
```

вы переменной `res` присвоили не значение строки:

```
 res = f'{n}:  {itemPrice} за {itemName}'
```

а значение, которое выдает функция `print`

поскольку функция `print` не выдает никакого значения (функция не возвращает значений), то переменной `res` присвоилось значение `None`

простой пример:

```
def func1(value)
    res = value * 2
    return res

def func2(value)
    res = value * 2

print(func1(10)) # вернет 20
print(func2(10)) # вернет None
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, с этим все понятно, если не делать **return** то ничего и не возвратится функции. Мне надо было сделать запись в файл, нашел инфу про print в Python3. Помогла такая конструкция `print(f'{n}:  {itemPrice} за {itemName}', file=open("items.html", "a", encoding='utf-8'))`